# Can I use Bootstrap for developing PWA & React

Tags: reactjs, responsive, progressive-web-apps

I am going to develop a cross platform mobile app using PWA and React and as I am new to these technologies I wonder what is the best and simplest way to make it responsive.

I know that it's possible to use Media Query.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/

But it seems more works to be done comparing to Bootstrap but unfortunately I couldn't find any document guiding me that is it possible to use these three in the same project or if there will be any conflict.

I would appreciate to have any advice regarding the best way to make a PWA and React project, responsive.

Comment: You can use basically every framework you can use to built a responsive website. A PWA is just a website with additional access to some selected features of the device through defined APIs. You can use whatever framework suits you that you would use to make a normal website responsive.

Comment: Thank you so much, Can I use Bootstrap for React or I have to use React-Responsive or React-Media?

Comment: You can use whatever you want. There is no real difference in making a responsive website vs making a PWA. But note that some features of bootstrap make use of jQuery which does to a some degree contradicts how react approaches things. If you are unfamiliar with any of these technologies you should start slow. Build just a website using react. If you feel somewhat comfortable add another framework. Don't rush it and try to do everything at once. React is complex enough to start with. There are some better alternatives with react. E.g. https://material-ui.com/ which is not driven by jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap, React, AngularJS or whatever library or framework that you prefer, there's some rules and you have to implement them in your application to make it PWA.